# Межпроцессное взаимодействие и вызов функций стороннего процесса с неизвестным API

Tags: c++, winapi

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать чтобы разобраться в алгоритме\ах вызова функций некого стороннего запущенного процесса (API которого неизвестно) из иного(своей программы).
Можно ли таким способом расширить\автоматизировать функционал стороннего процесса через свой процесс?

Comment: стоит в заголовке отразить, что *"программа не имеет открытых API"* и речь об эмуляции GUI действий к примеру с помощью AutoIt: *"вызвать n-ое нажатие определённых кнопок,... ввести в поле ввода"* (что далеко от каналов, сокетов, общей памяти и других обычных IPC средств).

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, но насколько я понимаю эмуляцию нажатия кнопок можно вызвать дергая обработчики нажатия (по сути функции) целевой программы из сторонней программы, а к примеру, дополнительные элементы графического интерфейса нарисовать поверх существующего. Прошу поправить если не прав.

Comment: как события GUI эмулируются это детали (которые в ответе можно осветить). Важно что обычные IPC для вас не работают, что в вопросе (заголовке) отразить следует (чтобы было ясно какого рода ответы ожидаются)¶ Сейчас прочитав заголовок я ожидаю ответ типа опубликованного (о каналах, сокетах), что читая внимательно тело вопроса скорее всего вам не подходит. Мой комментарий к тому, чтобы более специфичный заголовок вопроса сделать, чтобы помочь отвечающим и посетителям из гугла.

Comment: Хорошо, я изменил заголовок и тело темы.
Как я понял, предыдущие мои примеры являются частным случаем межпроцессного взаимодействия, но хотелось бы, в первую очередь, охватить всю тему.

Comment: теперь вопрос вообще не ясен.

Comment: Есть процесс А (API которого нам неизвестен, то есть наименования сигнатур открытых функций, структур и прочих членов).
Задача: создать процесс(приложение) Б, который сможет удаленно вызывать функции-члены приложения А (в том числе с передачей параметров из А в Б и обратно, если необходимо).
Разве это не межпроцессное взаимодействие?

Comment: Никак. Нет механизмов доступа к другому процессу, если он их не предоставляет. Процессы выполняются изолированно друг от друга и если они не предполагают "общения" с другими процессами, достучаться к ним невозможно. Изоляция процессов -- это основная функция операционной системы.

Comment: Термин "Межпроцессное взаимодействие" используется, когда говорят о взаимодействии со своими процессами. То, что вам нужно, видимо называется "взлом" или "обратная инженерия".

Answer (score 0):

Механизмов много: очереди сообщений, разделяемая память, каналы, межпроцессная синхронизация, сокеты.  Гуглите межпроцессное взаимодействие.

Из кросплатформенных библиотек есть [Boost.Interprocess](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html), если нужно что-то более специфичное - вероятно, придётся использовать напрямую winapi или специфичные для windows обёртки. Совсем без открытого API может не получиться - объекты межпроцессного взаимодействия обычно имеют глобальные строковые имена. Но если процесс создаётся как дочерний процесс, тогда можно создавать неименованные объекты взаимодействия (например, неименованный канал).